# Handling file download with gRPC on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, grpc, kotlin-coroutines

I currently have a gRPC server which is sending chunks of a video file. My android application written in Kotlin uses coroutines for UI updates (on Dispatchers.MAIN) and for handling a unidirectional stream of chunks (on Dispatchers.IO). Like the following:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
   viewModel.downloadUpdated().accept(DOWNLOAD_STATE.DOWNLOADING) // MAKE PROGRESS BAR VISIBLE

      GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
         stub.downloadVideo(request).forEach {
                file.appendBytes(
                    it.data.toByteArray()
                )
            }
      }.join()
      viewModel.downloadUpdated().accept(DOWNLOAD_STATE.FINISHED) // MAKE PROGRESS BAR DISAPPEAR
   } catch (exception: Exception) {
      viewModel.downloadUpdated().accept(DOWNLOAD_STATE.ERROR) // MAKE PROGRESS BAR DISAPPEAR
      screenNavigator.showError(exception) // SHOW DIALOG
   }
}
```

This works pretty well but I wonder if there is not a 'cleaner' way to handle downloads. I already know about DownloadManager but I feel like it only accepts HTTP queries and so I can't use my gRPC stub (I might be wrong, please tell me if so). I also checked WorkManager, and here is the same problem I do not know if this is the proper way of handling that case.

So, there are two questions here:

- Is there a way to handle gRPC queries in a clean way, meaning that I can now when it starts, finishes, fails and that I can cancel properly?
- If not, is there a better way to use coroutines for that ?

## EDIT

For those interested, I believe I came up with a dummy algorithm for downloading while updating the progress bar (open to improvments):

```
suspend fun downloadVideo(callback: suspend (currentBytesRead: Int) -> Unit) {
   println("download")

   stub.downloadVideo(request).forEach {
      val data = it.data.toByteArray()

      file.appendBytes(data)
      callback(x) // Where x is the percentage of download
   }
        
    println("downloaded")
}

class Fragment : CoroutineScope { //NOTE: The scope is the current Fragment
    private val job = Job()
    
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job
    
    fun onCancel() {
        if (job.isActive) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun updateLoadingBar(currentBytesRead: Int) {
        println(currentBytesRead)
    }
    
    fun onDownload() {
     
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            downloadVideo { currentBytes ->
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        
                    updateLoadingBar(currentBytes)
                    
                    if (job.isCancelled)
                        println("cancelled !")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, please check: [Introduction to coroutines](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Introduction%20to%20Coroutines%20and%20Channels/07_Progress)

## EDIT 2

As proposed in comments we could actually use Flows to handle this and it would give something like:

```
suspend fun foo(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
   println("download")
   stub.downloadVideo(request).forEach {
      val data = it.data.toByteArray()

      file.appendBytes(data)
      emit(x) // Where x is the percentage of download
   }
   println("downloaded")
}

class Fragment : CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()
    
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job
    
    fun onCancel() {
        if (job.isActive) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun updateLoadingBar(currentBytesRead: Int) {
        println(currentBytesRead)
    }
    
    fun onDownload() {
     
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                foo()
                    .onCompletion { cause -> println("Flow completed with $cause") }
                    .catch { e -> println("Caught $e") }
                    .collect { current -> 
                        if (job.isCancelled)
                            return@collect

                        updateLoadingBar(current)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`wire`](https://github.com/square/wire) supports gRPC since version 3.0. It may be helpful for your use case. It supports coroutines as well. [`Here`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo_zVPAXbBg) is a video where they talk about it.

Comment: @Emmanuel does they support version 3 of protocol buffers now ?

Comment: I do not think it does

Comment: Yeah, I already used wire in the pas and I changed because it supported only version 2. But it definitely have better kotlin support so I might consider moving back.

Comment: what about the tips for the downloading feature in grpc server ?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC can be many things so in that respect your question is unclear. Most importantly, it can be fully async and callback-based, which would mean it can be turned into a `Flow` that you can collect on the main thread. File writing, however, is blocking.

Your code seems to send the `FINISHED` signal right away, as soon as it has launched the download in the background. You should probably replace `launch(IO)` with `withContext(IO)`.

Comment: Yes gRPC can do a lot of things and here the app receives a stream of file’s chunk. Then I forgot the join() just after the launch(Dispatchers.IO), I updated that. Please note that I added “unidirectional stream of chunks” and the join function.

Comment: You should replace `launch` + `join` with `withContext`. If, on the gRPC level, you have a unidirectional chunk stream, it still doesn't say what API you consume it with. My suggestion is to use `Flow`. Flows are all about being self-contained, which makes exception handling straightforward: you just collect the flow in a `try-catch`. You can also cancel a flow by cancelling the coroutine that is collecting it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will try that. I would appreciate even a simple pseudo code to validate my idea. If you have time of course.

Comment: It's hard to show pseudocode on how to turn your existing stream into a Flow since I don't know what's behind it. If you had it, you'd write `chunkFlow.collect { file.writeChunk(it) }`.

Comment: Would it possible that you check the edit to validate ?

Comment: Your new code has explicit callback handling and also explicit context switching. It is OK in terms of "it works", but I feel you could get away with less manual work if you let Flow handle some of these concerns.

Comment: Definitely look more modern with flows, I updated the code. Thank you

Comment: You can improve it further, add `flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` as the last line in `suspend fun foo` (which BTW has no need to be `suspend` anymore) and remove both `withContext` wrappers from the calling side.